# Angular 4 - how to trigger an animation when a div comes into the viewport?

Tags: angular, animation, scroll, visible

I've been building a new site using Angular 4 and i'm trying to re-create a effect where when a div becomes visible (when you scroll down the screen) then that can then trigger a angular animation to slide the div in form the sides.

I've been able to do this in the past using jQuery outside of Angular 4 but i want to try and create the same effect using native Angular 4 animations.

Can anyone offer me advice on how to trigger an animation when a div comes into view (i.e. scrolled down to lower part of the page as it enters the viewport?). I have written the slide animations already but i don't know how to trigger that with a scroll when a div becomes visible at a later date to the view port.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Not sure but can this link be helpful https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#parallel-animation-groups ?

Comment: Hi Sandy, I did have a look through that and Parallel animation groups approach helps chain animations but it doesn't seem to have a way to trigger when a div enters the viewpoint after scrolling to a lower point of the page which could happen at a variable time when the used decides to scroll down to the div. Do you know any solution to this UI behaviour?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've created a directive that emits an event as soon as the element is either completely within view or it's upper edge has reached view's upper edge.

Here's a plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/mlez1dXjR87FNBHXq1YM/

It's used like this:

```html
<div (appear)="onAppear()">...</div>
```

Here's the directive:

```js
import {
  ElementRef, Output, Directive, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appear]'
})
export class AppearDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output()
  appear: EventEmitter<void>;

  elementPos: number;
  elementHeight: number;

  scrollPos: number;
  windowHeight: number;

  subscriptionScroll: Subscription;
  subscriptionResize: Subscription;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef){
    this.appear = new EventEmitter<void>();
  }

  saveDimensions() {
    this.elementPos = this.getOffsetTop(this.element.nativeElement);
    this.elementHeight = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }
  saveScrollPos() {
    this.scrollPos = window.scrollY;
  }
  getOffsetTop(element: any){
    let offsetTop = element.offsetTop || 0;
    if(element.offsetParent){
      offsetTop += this.getOffsetTop(element.offsetParent);
    }
    return offsetTop;
  }
  checkVisibility(){
    if(this.isVisible()){
      // double check dimensions (due to async loaded contents, e.g. images)
      this.saveDimensions();
      if(this.isVisible()){
        this.unsubscribe();
        this.appear.emit();
      }
    }
  }
  isVisible(){
    return this.scrollPos >= this.elementPos || (this.scrollPos + this.windowHeight) >= (this.elementPos + this.elementHeight);
  }

  subscribe(){
    this.subscriptionScroll = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll').startWith(null)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.saveScrollPos();
        this.checkVisibility();
      });
    this.subscriptionResize = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize').startWith(null)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.saveDimensions();
        this.checkVisibility();
      });
  }
  unsubscribe(){
    if(this.subscriptionScroll){
      this.subscriptionScroll.unsubscribe();
    }
    if(this.subscriptionResize){
      this.subscriptionResize.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.subscribe();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: for ie11 compatibillity you can change window.scrollY to document.documentElement.scrollTop.

Comment: this doesnt work properly with mutiple elements on the page

Comment: document.documentElement.scrollTop doesnt work in osx safari - its always 0

Comment: Is this okay to use in 2020? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: UPDATE: This code has to be updated to work in 2020.

Comment: UPDATE: This code has to use IntersectionObserver to be relevant in 2020

Answer (score 10):

[Martin Cremer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203752/12774458) answer updated to work with latest Rxjs and Angular versions, hope this helps

```js
import {
    ElementRef, Output, Directive, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appear]'
})
export class AppearDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @Output() appear: EventEmitter<void>;

    elementPos: number;
    elementHeight: number;

    scrollPos: number;
    windowHeight: number;

    subscriptionScroll: Subscription;
    subscriptionResize: Subscription;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
        this.appear = new EventEmitter<void>();
    }

    saveDimensions() {
        this.elementPos = this.getOffsetTop(this.element.nativeElement);
        this.elementHeight = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
        this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }
    saveScrollPos() {
        this.scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    }
    getOffsetTop(element: any) {
        let offsetTop = element.offsetTop || 0;
        if (element.offsetParent) {
            offsetTop += this.getOffsetTop(element.offsetParent);
        }
        return offsetTop;
    }
    checkVisibility() {
        if (this.isVisible()) {
            // double check dimensions (due to async loaded contents, e.g. images)
            this.saveDimensions();
            if (this.isVisible()) {
                this.unsubscribe();
                this.appear.emit();
            }
        }
    }
    isVisible() {
        return this.scrollPos >= this.elementPos || (this.scrollPos + this.windowHeight) >= (this.elementPos + this.elementHeight);
    }

    subscribe() {
        this.subscriptionScroll = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(startWith(null))
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.saveScrollPos();
                this.checkVisibility();
            });
        this.subscriptionResize = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(startWith(null))
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.saveDimensions();
                this.checkVisibility();
            });
    }
    unsubscribe() {
        if (this.subscriptionScroll) {
            this.subscriptionScroll.unsubscribe();
        }
        if (this.subscriptionResize) {
            this.subscriptionResize.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.subscribe();
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a base component that provides a flag *appearedOnce*, which turns true once if the component is either completely within view or it's upper edge has reached view's upper edge.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppearOnce implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  appearedOnce: boolean;

  elementPos: number;
  elementHeight: number;

  scrollPos: number;
  windowHeight: number;

  subscriptionScroll: Subscription;
  subscriptionResize: Subscription;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}
  onResize() {
    this.elementPos = this.getOffsetTop(this.element.nativeElement);
    this.elementHeight = this.element.nativeElement.clientHeight;
    this.checkVisibility();
  }
  onScroll() {
    this.scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    this.checkVisibility();
  }
  getOffsetTop(element: any){
    let offsetTop = element.offsetTop || 0;
    if(element.offsetParent){
      offsetTop += this.getOffsetTop(element.offsetParent);
    }
    return offsetTop;
  }

  checkVisibility(){
    if(!this.appearedOnce){
      if(this.scrollPos >= this.elementPos || (this.scrollPos + this.windowHeight) >= (this.elementPos + this.elementHeight)){
        this.appearedOnce = true;
        this.unsubscribe();
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      }
    }
  }

  subscribe(){
    this.subscriptionScroll = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll').startWith(null)
      .subscribe(() => this.onScroll());
    this.subscriptionResize = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize').startWith(null)
      .subscribe(() => this.onResize());
  }
  unsubscribe(){
    if(this.subscriptionScroll){
      this.subscriptionScroll.unsubscribe();
    }
    if(this.subscriptionResize){
      this.subscriptionResize.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.subscribe();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You can simply extend this component and make use of the *appearedOnce* property by inheritance

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngIf="appearedOnce">...</div>
      ...
    </div>
  `
})
class MyComponent extends AppearOnceComponent {
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind to call super() if you need to overwrite constructor or lifecyclehooks.

(edit) **plunker**:
https://embed.plnkr.co/yIpA1mI1b9kVoEXGy6Hh/

(edit) i've turned this into a directive in another answer below.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thats a really interesting solution. Could you describe how to implement the same logic in a existing component and what imports are needed for the component. I'm relatively new to angular and would really welcome the detail on implementation. thanks.

Comment: i've created a little plnkr:
https://embed.plnkr.co/yIpA1mI1b9kVoEXGy6Hh/

There's an example component (TurnGreenWhenInViewComponent) that extends AppearOnce and uses it's appearedOnce flag to turn green after it appeared once.

Comment: i've added another answer with almost the same thing, but as a directive.

Comment: I tried to implement this solution. However, when I call `super()` it tells me I need to give it 2 parameters. Looking at the constructor you use: `private element: ElementRef, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef`. What should that be?

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina ElementRef and ChangeDetectorRef i guess

Answer (score 2):

A simple way if you want it in a specific component:

```
@ViewChild('chatTeaser') chatTeaser: ElementRef;

@HostListener('window:scroll')
checkScroll() {
    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;

    if (this.chatTeaser && this.chatTeaser.nativeElement.offsetTop >= scrollPosition) {
        this.animateAvatars();
    }
}
```

And in html:

```
<div id="chat-teaser" #chatTeaser>
```

Exactly when the top of the element is scrolled to the function is called. If you want to call the function only when the full div is in view add the div height to `this.chatTeaser.nativeElement.offsetTop`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by Martin Cremer is perfect.

Unless you want this to work on a angular app using ssr

###### `Angular Universal`

I have modified the existing accepted answer to work in ssr below

###### Create an injectable service to be able to use window object in backend

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface ICustomWindow extends Window {
  __custom_global_stuff: string;
}

function getWindow (): any {
  return window;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WindowService {
  get nativeWindow (): ICustomWindow {
    return getWindow();
  }
}
```

###### Now, create a directive to notify when the element is in viewable area

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowService } from './window.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appear]'
})
export class AppearDirective {

  windowHeight: number = 0;
  elementHeight: number = 0;
  elementPos: number = 0;

  @Output()
  appear: EventEmitter<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private window: WindowService
  ) {
    this.appear = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  }

  checkVisible() {
    if (this.elementPos < this.window.nativeWindow.scrollY + this.windowHeight) {
      this.appear.emit(true);
      this.appear.complete();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  onScroll() {
    this.checkVisible();
  }

  @HostListener('window:load', [])
  onLoad() {
    this.windowHeight = (this.window.nativeWindow.innerHeight);
    this.elementHeight = (this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement).offsetHeight;
    this.elementPos = (this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement).offsetTop;
    this.checkVisible();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', [])
  onResize() {
    this.windowHeight = (this.window.nativeWindow.innerHeight);
    this.elementHeight = (this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement).offsetHeight;
    this.elementPos = (this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement).offsetTop;
    this.checkVisible();
  }

}
```

###### Create a new function in the component

```js
onAppear() {
    // TODO: do something
}
```

###### Add the directive to your element

```html
<!-- ... -->
<h2 (appear)="onAppear()">Visible</h2>
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer API which is designed to handle this exact problem: [IntersevtionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Using this will allow you to do away with all the manual offset calculations & keeping local state. Here's a simple example using this API:

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, Output } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @description
 * Emits the `appear` event when the element comes into view in the viewport.
 *
 */
@Directive({
    selector: '[visibleSpy]',
})
export class OnVisibleDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @Output() appear = new EventEmitter<void>();
    private observer: IntersectionObserver;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const options = {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: '0px',
            threshold: 0,
        };

        this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    this.appear.next();
                }
            });
        }, options);

        this.observer.observe(this.element.nativeElement);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.observer.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of an infinity scroll; it triggers `handleScrollEvent()` when the element comes inside the viewport.

inside `item-grid.component.html`

```
<span [ngClass]="{hidden: curpage==maxpage}" (window:scroll)="handleScrollEvent()" (window:resize)="handleScrollEvent()" #loadmoreBtn (click)="handleLoadMore()">Load more</span>
```

inside `item-grid.component.ts`:

```
@ViewChild('loadmoreBtn') loadmoreBtn: ElementRef;
curpage: number;
maxpage: number;

ngOnInit() {
  this.curpage = 1;
  this.maxpage = 5;
}

handleScrollEvent() {
  const { x, y } = this.loadmoreBtn.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (y < window.innerHeight && this.maxpage > this.curpage) {
    this.curpage++;
  }
}
```