# Angular 6 - Animate Div on Scroll

Tags: angular, animation

I need advise =)

I would like to implement animations similar to [AOS, WOW.JS, ScrollMagic Demo ] but without using any API to my angular project.

Is there any reliable source/tutorial, with regards on the following animations.

As i have read through https://angular.io/guide/animations but there isn't any help with or direction to it.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, if you don't wanna any third party dependency build your self a **web component** with [stencijs](https://stenciljs.com/) or [react](https://reactjs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is some form of scroll directive in handler which basically checks for the window.scrollY event and save the scrolled position , it should also check with respect to offset position for the native element and save these dimensions so that you can basically do the animate operation .Please visit this [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/mlez1dXjR87FNBHXq1YM/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573489/angular-4-how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-a-div-comes-into-the-viewport) stackoverflow answer