# Integrate AOS library with Angular4 application

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins, angular-animations

I am working on Angular 4.4.6 application and I want to implement some animations on scroll using the awesome plugin [AOS](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos)

my code:

app.component.ts

```
import * as AOS from 'aos';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
 encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 ngOnInit(){
  AOS.init();
 }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="box" data-aos="slide-left">
      <img src="assets/imgs/seo.png" alt="">
</div>
```

angulr.cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css",
    "../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js"
  ],
```

I've tried the answer here with no hope
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44808496/4183947

**Note:** I've no errors in my console.

Answer (score 23):

I'm trying to get the same thing working for a site I'm migrating to Angular 4.2.4. Since you included the path to the AOS stylesheet in your `angular.cli.json` you probably already installed AOS via:

```
npm install aos --save
```

I got it running with the following:

```
// angular.cli.json
...
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css",
  "styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [],
...
```

and:

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as AOS from 'aos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
    AOS.init();
  }
}
```

and in my case I have markup in a HomeComponent:

```
// home.component.html
...
<div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true">
  the content
</div>
...
```

I might explore using AOS via the Angular Dependency Injection system in the future, as described in [animate into view when scrolled to angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821160/animate-into-view-when-scrolled-to-angular2/44808496#44808496) but simply importing AOS in `app.component.ts` is working so far.

Comment: We are not using `ng-cli`, so have to import the css from our entry scss file.
`@import "~aos/dist/aos.css"`.
 
Works like a charm. Thanks Bro!

Comment: How is this different from the question itself? I still don't find the error and why it does not work.

Answer (score 15):

```
npm install aos --save
```

Edit angular.cli.json

```
// angular.cli.json
...
"styles": [
"../node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css",
"styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
"../node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js"
],
...
```

App Component

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as AOS from 'aos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
    AOS.init();
  }
}
```

In component html or where you want to add animation

```
...
<div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true">
  the content
</div>
...
```

Comment: This worked for me with Angular9.  Looks like the js import is required as well as the css import.

Answer (score 8):

**I do this in Angular 12+**

First, install AOS with your Terminal

```
npm install --save aos
```

Then install AOS types for typescript support.

```
npm install --save @types/aos
```

add AOS styles and script to project from :
**angular.json > architect > build > options >**

```
"styles": [
   "./node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css"
 ],

"scripts": [
   "./node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js"
 ]
```

Init AOS to the AppComponent or any component you want to use it.

```
import * as AOS from 'aos';

ngOnInit() {
   AOS.init();
}
```

Use AOS attributes on the elements

```
<div data-aos="fade-up"> Your Content </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Terminal

```
# if you use npm
npm install aos -s

# if you use yarn
yarn add aos
```

> styles.scss

```
@import 'aos/dist/aos.css'; //<------ Add this line to the top
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as AOS from 'aos'; //<------ Add this line

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        AOS.init(); //<------ Add this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For angular9+

do

```sh
npm install aos --save
```

add js and css file in `angular.json`

```
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js"
            ]
```

In the app component (your root component), call AOS.init()

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    AOS.init();
  }
}
```

Stop your if you are already running and then start again because you have changes in angular.json file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have install all 3 Dependencies.

```
npm i classlist-polyfill
npm i lodash.debounce
npm i lodash.throttle
```

you can check here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aos#init-aos