# Error importing aos when ng serve is called

Tags: angular

I am not able to import aos in angular js it is showing the below error when ever i am trying to run ng serve? It is saying aos module is not declared?

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:3:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'aos'. 'C:/Users/greni/OneDrive/Desktop/angular/gameweb/node_modules/aos/dist/aos.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/aos` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'aos';`
```

3 `import * as AOS from 'aos';`
code i have written in appcomponent.js

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as AOS from 'aos';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'app';
ngOnInit() {
AOS.init(); }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253364/integrate-aos-library-with-angular4-application as I am also looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to install this devDependency `"@types/aos": "^3.0.7"`, my package.json looks something like:

```
{
  ...,
  "devDependencies": {
     ...,
     "@types/aos": "^3.0.7",
     ...
  }
}
```